# Storage set JSON : Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-storage

I am using storage from `@ionic/storage`and `cordova-sqlite-storage` to save `models` in `localstorage`. In my example:

```
this.storage.set(this.storageKey, model).then(value => {
    resolve();
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

But this error appears:

> VM1799:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

I got more informations by clicking on `VM1799:1`in the Chrome DevTools, and it seems that my models are not well parsed, but I can't understand why :

```
cordova.callbackFromNative(
    'SQLitePluginXXX', 
     true, 
     1, 
     [
         [
             {
                 "type":"success",
                 "result": {
                     "rowsAffected": 0
                 }
             },
             {
                 "type":"success",
                 "result": {
                     "rows": [
                         {
                             "id": 1,
                             "key": "cities",
                             "value": "[{\"_id\":\"XXX\",\"name\":{\"en\":\"London\"}]" // As you can see, some extra backslashs are added
                         },
                         { ... }
                     ]
                 }
             }
          ]
     ]
 )
```

Comment: My bad, I forgot to add it here. Just to be clear I didn't implement this function, it seems that `cordova` calls it while `storage.set`.

Comment: do u need that `resolve()` for a promise out of view or something?

Comment: What happens if you try to save a string version of your model? Something like `this.storage.set(this.storageKey, JSON.stringify(model))`

Comment: @sebaferreras I already tried, but nothing has changed, still the same ...